# curves and projections to axis or coordinates

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth surface and $C$ a smooth curve, over $\mathbb C$. Let $P\in X$, $c_0\in C$, and $C'$ a smooth curve in $X\times C$ such that $x=(P,c_0)\in C'$. Let
$$p:X\times C\longrightarrow C$$
be the projection.
Suppose that $C'$ is transverse to  $p^{-1}(c_0)$ at $x$.

Question: does there exist neigbourhoods $U$ of $P$ and $V$ of $c_0$ such that, for every $v\in V$, $p^{-1}(v)\cap U$ contains exactly one point?

Comment: It is not a good idea to denote a curve by $S$.

Comment: @Sacha Thank you very much. I found this problem when trying to study flat deformations of the ideal sheaf of one point $P$ on the surface $X$. They are sheaves of the form $I\otimes L$, where $I$ is the ideal sheaf of one point, and $L$ a line bundle on $X$. I wanted to see if this could be done by only a local study around $P$. Apparently no

Answer (score 0):

The surface $X$ is irrelevant for the problem. You just have a morphism of smooth curves $f : C' \to C$ which is etale at point $c_0 \in C'$ and you are asking if it is birational. Indeed, for any such morphism you can choose an embedding $C' \subset X$ into a smooth surface and consider the product map $C' \hookrightarrow X \times C$.

Now, the answer to the question is negative. For example, you can take any finite covering $f:C'' \to C$ of degree larger than 1, take $c_0 \in C''$ to be a point away from the ramification divisor, and set
$$
C' = C'' \setminus (f^{-1}(f(c_0)) \setminus \{c_0\}).
$$
In other words, consider remove from $C''$ all points in the fiber of $c_0$ except for $c_0$ itself.